# Notification for increase reputation error?

Tags: support, reputation, notifications

Today I had accepted an answer and I saw wrong notification as below:

[image]
Please compare menu-bar reputation and reputation of icon in question.
It should be +2, but it shows +1.

Is it bug? Or may be I am wrong?

May complete on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Here is question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775740/stsspring-tool-suite-and-eclipse

Comment: Note that the -1 from yesterday is also highlighted blue. 2 - 1 = 1.

Comment: Ah... as yesterday question ,, pls comment if you cast downvote . I would like to know what I am wrong.

Comment: I did not downvote you, but on meta if you say something is wrong and it isn't, some people will downvote to show they disagree

Comment: **-1 is on meta.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You lost 1 rep yesterday (from a +1 and -3 on a question, net loss of 1). You hadn't clicked on the button since that rep change.

Therefore your *net* rep change was +1, and that was shown on the rep indicator. The *net* rep change is the change shown on the rep indicator, not just the total of all positive rep.

Comment: It is first time for me ! and I am sure at yesterday , I didn't cast any downvote ! Has another situation ?

Comment: @Cataclysm It looks like it was because your meta question was downvoted three times, but was upvoted once (net change of -1) rep.

Comment: where .... ? I didn't see. Pls don't be mix with meta.

Comment: I never casted any downvote yesterday and before !

Comment: @Cataclysm See my above comment...

Comment: do you mean , it is concern with meta rep ? sorry for my stupid question.

Comment: @Cataclysm but mixing with meta is just what that thing does. If I get +10 on one site, +5 on another and -2 on a third, it shows the total across all the sites (eg +13)

Comment: no no no !! @KateGregory  .. before it , I often get downvotes on my questions of meta , but my StackOverFlow rep does not flow..

Comment: @Cataclysm - seems you're not understanding the info people are giving. Take a bit of time to read the answer/comments etc.

Comment: @Cataclysm the +1 in the top bar does not mean "your SO rep has gone up by 1" it means "all of the rep changes across all of the sites since you last looked at this total +1" The -1 on meta doesn't affect your SO rep but it does affect what the top bar shows

Comment: @James OK sir ! I am waiting. I complained because I really didn't understand yet.

Comment: @KateGregory Thank you sir ! Now I understand with your comment. Thanks in advance sir. Have a nice day :D. And It is first time for me.

Comment: ...sir? Now *I'm* confused.

Comment: @DennisMeng I'm guessing English isn't the OP's first language from "it is concern with meta rep?". The only culture-crossing gender indicator I've spotted is a name ending in _a_ being female more often than male. No clues in "Kate" unless you know that's a female name; c.f. "Nate". What genders would you guess for "Ravindra", "Mehak", "Xin Yi" or "Kwok Yip"?

Comment: @AndrewC fair enough

Comment: For the record, and since I can't bear to leave that one hanging, the answers are Male, Female, Female, Male (although I seem to recall that Xin Yi is more  surprising for Mandarin speakers than it seems to me).